# How to setup tsconfig paths in jest.config.js. Angular 8. jest-preset-angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I have absolute paths set up in my tsconfig that work as expected during serve however do not work for jest.

An example path looks like this:

```
"paths": {
    "@shared": "src/app/shared/index.ts"
}
```

Then in a component I can use

```
import { MySharedComponent, MyOtherSharedComponent } from '@shared';
```

I am currently trying to move to Jest for testing. In my jest.config.js I have a moduleNameMapper section:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '@shared/(.*)': 'src/app/shared/$1'
}
```

This results in

```
cannot find module @Shared
```

If I change my tsconfig path to this:

```
"paths": {
    "@shared/*": "src/app/shared/*"
}
```

these no longer work

```
import { MySharedComponent, MyOtherSharedComponent } from '@shared';
```

and have to be updated to this

```
import { MySharedComponent } from '@shared/my-shared.component';
import { MyOtherSharedComponent } from '@shared/my-other-shared.component';
```

the tests work fine and the project runs ok however it is a large project and I have hundreds of imports that use this format

```
import { MySharedComponent, MyOtherSharedComponent } from '@shared';
```

Is there a way to get moduleNameMapper to work with this path

```
"@shared": "src/app/shared/index.ts"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I had to update the imports to use the full path e.g. import { MySharedComponent } from '@shared/my-shared.component';

Answer (score 3):

You can have several `paths` for `@shared` in `tsconfig.json`, one for the `index.ts` and others for sub-paths:

```
"paths": {
    "@shared": "src/app/shared/index.ts",
    "@shared/*": "src/app/shared/*"
}
```

For the moduleNameMapper you can also add a second one:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
    '@shared/(.*)': 'src/app/shared/$1',
    '@shared': 'src/app/shared/index.ts'
}
```